# Prove that the relation $x^n + y^n = z^n$ does not hold for $n \geq z$

Tags: number-theory

> Assume $x, y, z$, and $n$ are positive integers, and $n \geq z$. Prove that the relation $x^n + y^n = z^n$ does not hold.

I find it hard to relate the condition $n \geq z$ to solve this question. Maybe this is best proved by induction. I could start with $n = 1$. Then we have $x+y = 1$ for which there exist no positive integer solutions $(x,y)$. We can then assume the statement is true for some $k \geq z$. Thus there exist no positive integer solution pairs $(x,y)$ to $x^k+y^k = z^k$. We have to show it is the same for $x^{k+1}+y^{k+1} = z^{k+1}$.

Comment: ''Is it allowed to use the Last Fermat's Theorem?

Comment: @ajotatxe Then the question would be quite trivial, yes?

Comment: If you had such a relation, you would necessarily have $x,y < z$. What is $2(z-1)^n$?

Comment: @DanielFischer It is $2(z^n-(\binom{n}{1}z^{n-1}+\cdots+(-1)^n)$.

Comment: That too, but that's not particularly helpful, I think. Perhaps I should have asked what $\dfrac{2(z-1)^n}{z^n}$ is.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am not sure how much different that is from my expression.

Comment: Lol. Which teacher casually assigned you Fermat's Last Theorem as assignment ? xD

Comment: It took four centuries of human thought to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since we assume that $x,y,z$ are positive integers, we have $x^n + y^n > y^n$, and since $a \mapsto a^n$ is monotonic, it follows that $x^n + y^n > z^n$ if $y \geqslant z$. By the same reasoning we can exclude $x \geqslant z$.

For $x,y < z$, we then have $x^n + y^n \leqslant 2(z-1)^n$, and then showing $2(z-1)^n < z^n$ finishes the proof. Since by assumption $n \geqslant z$, we have

$$\frac{(z-1)^n}{z^n} = \biggl(1 - \frac{1}{z}\biggr)^n \leqslant \biggl( 1 - \frac{1}{z}\biggr)^z,$$

and it is easily shown if not already known that

$$\biggl(1 - \frac{1}{z}\biggr)^z < e^{-1}$$

for all positive integers $z$. Hence

$$\frac{2(z-1)^n}{z^n} < \frac{2}{e} < 1.$$

Comment: What does this show?

Comment: That $x,y < z \implies x^n + y^n < z^n$ if $n \geqslant z$.

Comment: It is a little unclear to me how you get that $x^n+y^n \leq 2(z-1)^n$ if $x,y < z$. Obviously $x^n+y^n < 2z^n$ as a result, but how does this imply $x^n + y^n \leq 2(z-1)^n$?

Comment: If $x,y < z$, then, since we're dealing with integers, $x,y \leqslant (z-1)$. Hence $x^n + y^n \leqslant (z-1)^n + (z-1)^n$.

Comment: @DanelFischer How would you prove that $\left(1-\dfrac{1}{z}\right)^z < e^{-1}$?

Comment: For example by taking the $z^{\text{th}}$ root, the inequality is equivalent to $1 - \frac{1}{z} < e^{-1/z}$. Since the exponential function is strictly convex and $\exp'(0) = 1$, we have $1+t < e^t$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$, in particular for $t = -\frac{1}{z}$.